# Keyword arguments in python class inheritance

Tags: python, class, inheritance, metaclass, python-class

Hello I am recently looking about the `metaclass` in Python.

I learned about we can attach a metaclass to a class in this way:

```py
class Metaclass(type):
    ...

class MyClass(metaclass=Metaclass):
    ...
```

- The first question

I wonder what's the principle of the keyword argument (`metaclass=...`) in the above example. There seems no description for that in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)

I know that there is keyword argument for a function, but I've never seen the form occurred in class inheritance.

- The second question

We know that we can create a class using `type()` function in this way

```py
cls = type(class_name, (base_class,), {func_name: func_ref})
```

Considering the `metaclass=...` form, how can I pass metaclass when creating class using `type()` instead of `class` keyword?

Thanks stackoverflowers!

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses) answer the first question?

Comment: The `metaclass` kwarg *is* mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses)

Comment: Per the same docs, setting a metaclass using `type(_, _, _)` does not *seem* to be possible

Comment: @timgeb Thank you. Yes I've looked this, but it doesn't provide something about principle of keyword argument in class inheritance, I am still confused

Comment: The meta class is the thing you call, not an argument you pass to `type`. `type(_, _, _)` gets replaced with `Metaclass(_, _, _)`.

Comment: The treatment of a `class` statement is discussed in [Section 3.3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation) of the language documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the keyword arguments used with a `class` statement are passed to `__init_subclass__`, to be used however that function sees fit. `metaclass`, however, is used by the code generator itself to determine what gets called in order to define the class.

The metaclass is not an argument to be passed to a call to `type`; it is the callable that gets called *instead* of `type`. Very roughly speaking,

```
class MyClass(metaclass=Metaclass):
    ...
```

is turned into

```
MyClass = Metaclass('MyClass', (), ...)
```

`type` is simply the default metaclass.

(The gory details of how a `class` statement is executed can be found [in Section 3.3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation) of the language documentation.)

---

Note that a metaclass does not have to be a subclass of `type`. You can do truly horrific things with metaclasses, like

```
>>> class A(metaclass=lambda x, y, z: 3): pass
...
>>> type(A)
<class 'int'>
>>> A
3
```

It doesn't really matter what the metaclass *returns*, as long as it accepts 3 arguments.

Please don't write actual code like this, though. A `class` statement should produce something that at least *resembles* a type.

---

In some sense, `class` statements are less magical than other statements. `def` statements, for example, can't be customized to produce something other than instances of `function`, and it's far harder to create a `function` object by calling `types.FunctionType` explicitly.

Comment: class MyClass(metaclass=Metaclass):
    ...
is turned into

MyClass = Metaclass('MyClass', (), ...)

Comment: Thanks! `class MyClass(metaclass=Metaclass):` is turned into `MyClass = Metaclass('MyClass', (), ...)` really helps. And can I ask another question?

So there is only one form of that `keyword argument` in the class definition, right?
If not, are there more keyword argument besides `metaclass`?

Could you tell me the source code of the logic of the translation from `class MyClass(metaclass=Metaclass):` to `MyClass = Metaclass('MyClass', (), ...)` in the cpython    repository?

Comment: `metaclass` is, I believe, the only keyword argument that the Python interpreter knows and cares about and looks for. Other keyword arguments are just passed on to other hooks (like `__init_subclass__`) when present. As for source code, you'd have to dig into the source of the implementation (e.g., CPython).

Comment: Horrific `A`, +1

Comment: I'll mention in passing the [PEP 560](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0560/) appears to provide a rationale for using non-types as meta classes.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes I've looked this, but it doesn't provide something about principle of keyword argument in class inheritance, I am still confused

`metaclass=...` is not about inheritance.

Everything in Python is an object. So when you define a class `MyClass`, not only is `MyClass()` an object but the class `MyClass` itself is an object.

`MyClass()` is an instance of `MyClass`, simple enough.

But if `MyClass` is also an object, what class is it an instance of?

If you do nothing, the object (!) `MyClass` is an instance of the class `type`.

If you do `class MyClass(metaclass=Metaclass)` then `MyClass` is an instance of `Metaclass`.

Consider

```
class Metaclass(type):
    pass

class MyClass1:
    pass

class MyClass2(metaclass=Metaclass):
    pass
```

Both `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` inherit from `object` and only `object`.

```
>>> MyClass1.__mro__
(<class '__main__.MyClass1'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> MyClass2.__mro__
(<class '__main__.MyClass2'>, <class 'object'>)
```

But their types differ:

```
>>> type(MyClass1)
<class 'type'>
>>> type(MyClass2)
<class '__main__.Metaclass'>
```

When would you need this? Usually, you don't. And when you do, you do the kind of metaprogramming where you already know the why and how.